# Dynamically add SWFObject using Wicket

Tags: java, flash, wicket

I am trying to add a Flash (*.swf) file to my Wicket application. I found some information [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/object-container-adding-flash-to-a-wicket-application.html), but unfortunately it is not working, and I don't know why. On a web page, the elements and tag

`<object wicket:id="swf" data="resources/test.swf" width="700" height="70" style="float: right; margin: 15px 0 0 0;"></object>`

render as

`<object height="70" style="float: right; margin: 15px 0 0 0;" width="140" data="../../resources/wicketapp.ViewPanel/resources/test.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="movie" value="../../resources/wicketapp.ViewPanel/resources/test.swf">
</object>`

Clearly, this is not the path of my Flash file. Also, I want to load the file dynamically, but the method of embedding Flash discussed in the above link is static. How can I load swf files dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the linked implementation, if you want an absolute path you should precede it with a slash:

```
// if it's an absolute path, return it:
if( src.startsWith( "/" ) || src.startsWith( "http://" ) || src.startsWith( "https://" ) )
  return(src);
```

Otherwise a wicket resource path is generated.

I'd actually recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding flash - there is some nice wicket integration code at the start of [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/open-flash-chart-and-wicket.html), along with a flash-based component that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood your question, your want change swf file in runtime. I have solve this problem as shown below (this is Scala code, but I suppose that you understand it):

```
class SWFObject(id: String) extends WebComponent(id)
with LoggerSupport {

  def script: String = """
        var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";
        var xiSwfUrlStr = "flash/playerProductInstall.swf";
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.quality = "high";
        params.bgcolor = "#ebf4ff";
        params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.align = "middle";
        swfobject.embedSWF(
                "${name}", "flashContent",
                "100%", "100%",
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
                flashvars, params, attributes);
        swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
  """

  /**
   * Path to SWF file.
   */
  var swfFile: String = _;

  override def onComponentTag(tag: ComponentTag) = {
    checkComponentTag(tag, "script")
  }

  override def onComponentTagBody(markupStream: MarkupStream, openTag: ComponentTag) = {
    val relativeName = getRequestCycle()
      .getProcessor()
      .getRequestCodingStrategy()
      .rewriteStaticRelativeUrl(swfFile)


    val body = body.replace("${name}", relativeName)
    replaceComponentTagBody(markupStream, openTag, body)
  }
}
```

Here are example of using:

```
  private val gameObject = new SWFObject("game");
  gameObject.swfFile = "flash/" + swfFile;
```

HTML is used swfobject script and based on standard FlashBuilder export.